# Android Volley not being recognized as POST on server with php

Tags: java, php, android, android-volley

I am using volley to sent post to my server. in my php inside insert.php i have code like this

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

   //do all post functions
}
 else{
//notofication that says its not post

}
```

This is my volley code in my android

```
String HttpUrl = "http://192.168.30.18/insert.php";

    // Creating string request with post method
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, HttpUrl,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String ServerResponse) {

                    // Hiding the progress dialog after all task complete.
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    // Showing response message coming from server.
                    Toast.makeText(CreateAccountOrLoginActivity.this, ServerResponse, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d("responseSuccess",ServerResponse);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                    // Hiding the progress dialog after all task complete.
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    // Showing error message if something goes wrong.
                    Toast.makeText(CreateAccountOrLoginActivity.this, volleyError.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d("responseFail",volleyError.toString());
                }
            }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {



            // Creating Map String Params.
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // Adding All values to Params.
            params.put("title",title);
            params.put("name", fname);
            params.put("surname", sname);
           


            return params;
        }

    };

    // Creating RequestQueue.
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(CreateAccountOrLoginActivity.this);

    // Adding the StringRequest object into requestQueue.
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

The problem  is after the android code is run, it returns what is in the else statement of the insert.php instead of what is in the if statement, meaning it is not being recognized as a post. How do i resolve it to make it run in the if statement

Comment: Have you checked if all the params came in as GET?

Comment: `String HttpUrl = "192.168.30.11/insert.php` It is hard to believe that that should not be `String HttpUrl = "http://192.168.30.11/insert.php` or `String HttpUrl = "https://192.168.30.11/insert.php`.

Comment: @blackapps sorry had manually put the url in the question, but it was always http://192.168.30.11/insert.php

Comment: Ok. Please answer my first comment.

Comment: @blackapps how do i check if all params came in as GET?

Comment: That is elementary php programming. I'm not here to teach you that. But think about it: how would you check them if they came in as POST?

Comment: `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')` Shouldnt you use '===' instead of '=='?

Comment: it is working like that if i use the POST straight from a php form. but it is not working if i am using from the android volley

Comment: check this out, https://www.android-examples.com/volley-post-request-php-mysql/